# Why have the default link colors changed in my rails app?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have started writing an app in rails and noticed that the links do not have the expected colors. The color of the links are a dark grey-blue color, different from the standard bootstrap colors, and when I hover over the links, their background color is black. Why is this happening? I'm guessing it may be my gems, so here are the gems I have added:

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-uncommon_password'
gem 'faker'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'haikunator'
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'bootstrap-kaminari-views'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
```

Comment: Did you create some scaffold?

Comment: Does scaffolding create default css?

Comment: Yes, check your app/assets/stylesheets folder.

Comment: Great, thank you! If you want to turn this into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you run the `rails scaffold` command, you'll see something like:

```
$ bin/rails generate scaffold HighScore game:string score:integer
    invoke  active_record
    create    db/migrate/20130717151933_create_high_scores.rb
    create    app/models/high_score.rb
    invoke    test_unit
    create      test/models/high_score_test.rb
    create      test/fixtures/high_scores.yml
    invoke  resource_route
     route    resources :high_scores
    invoke  scaffold_controller
    create    app/controllers/high_scores_controller.rb
    invoke    erb
    create      app/views/high_scores
    create      app/views/high_scores/index.html.erb
    create      app/views/high_scores/edit.html.erb
    create      app/views/high_scores/show.html.erb
    create      app/views/high_scores/new.html.erb
    create      app/views/high_scores/_form.html.erb
    invoke    test_unit
    create      test/controllers/high_scores_controller_test.rb
    invoke    helper
    create      app/helpers/high_scores_helper.rb
    invoke    jbuilder
    create      app/views/high_scores/index.json.jbuilder
    create      app/views/high_scores/show.json.jbuilder
    invoke  assets
    invoke    coffee
    create      app/assets/javascripts/high_scores.coffee
    invoke    scss
    create      app/assets/stylesheets/high_scores.scss
    invoke  scss
   identical    app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.scss
```

Check the last part, Rails create an scaffolds.scss file, and another one for your model, by default the one for the model doesn't contain CSS rules, but the scaffold one has, so, you could try removing it.

You could also try the `--no-stylesheets` or `--no-scaffold-stylesheet` flags to not generate unneeded CSS files.

Comment: You can also [configure the generator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-generators) in your `development.rb` to not generate them (`stylesheets` and `scaffold_stylesheet` are of interest on the link). If you never want to generate them, so you don't have to keep passing the option in.